# How can I set up the python environment variable on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, python, environment-variables

I would sure like to be able to type "python" on my command line instead of C:\Python27\python.exe. So to that end I'm trying to get the environment variable set up for myself.

Problem is, I can't seem to get the Python system environment variable to set up on my Windows 7 install. So far I have (as variable PYTHONPATH):

```
C:\Python27;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk;C:\Python27\Scripts;
```

Not sure why that won't work. I've tried with a trailing semicolon and without, with backslashes at the end of the folders, and everything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the Python directory as your PATH, not PYTHONPATH. The latter is a separate variable that Python uses. Also, you only need the main directory (`C:\Python27`).

Comment: Awesome. That's something none of the little pseudo-tutorials told me :P

Answer (score 0):

Control Panel>System

Advanced Settings (Hyperlink-like-text) brings up the XP "System" dialog.

Under the Advanced Tab: Environment Variables button

In the Environment Variables Dialog

you can add it to the PATH variable as a User variable or System Variable.

Comment: Windows 7, not XP.

Comment: That is for Windows 7